# How to incorporate Python libraries in C?

Tags: python, c, wrapper

Like many libraries coded in C can be wrapped over for Python,
Is there any *general* way to do other way around ?

Answer (score 5):

[Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/#embedding-the-cpython-runtime-in-a-larger-application).  (embed the CPython interpreter in your C/C++ application and that way you can make use of Python libraries.)